# How to create an desktop application that appear in the top menu bar?

Tags: application-development

I'm new to Ubuntu desktop app development. But I'm an experienced Python developer and also a web developer.

How to create an app that appear in the top bar like 'redshift' and 'google chrome'?

[image]

Can I make it with python qt? or ubuntu-sdk?

where should I start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a system tray. In Qt there is a class for that: `QSystemTrayIcon`.

It should work on all supported platforms.